# Convert a full address to a separated by, city, region, zip code, etc

Tags: php, web-services, geolocation

I have been searched by the internet, however I didn't find a perfect solution, so I faith that someone already did something like this.

So my issue is, I'm using a webservice were you send the VAT number and if is valid you got the Company info. However the address received is the full address not divided by parts.

For example: 
Google Ireland VAT is IE6388047V

I got:
Company Name: GOOGLE IRELAND LIMITED
Address: 3RD FLOOR ,GORDON HOUSE ,BARROW STREET ,DUBLIN 4

So what I need is something like this:
3RD FLOOR ,GORDON HOUSE ,BARROW STREET ,DUBLIN 4 
Converts this to:

Address: Ringsend Post Office, Gordon House, Barrow St

City: Dublin 4

Country: Ireland

Someone can help me and make the day? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried this geocomplete jquery library. This example is similar to what you are looking for `http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/form.html`

Comment: @sabinadhikari yes I Has, but if you try put the Google IE (GOOGLE IRELAND LIMITED 3RD FLOOR ,GORDON HOUSE ,BARROW STREET ,DUBLIN 4 ), for instance, we don't receive any response. I think this could be a good solution however is not a perfect one...

Comment: If you search 'GORDON HOUSE ,BARROW STREET ,DUBLIN 4' only in geocomplete it will give formatted address. So for that you can split the whole string into two parts and search with the second part of the string.

Comment: @sabinadhikari you are right, but to do that I need to create a little brain to know which parts I should ignore. This feature is to deal with all world addresses. :\

Comment: if you are using php explode the string which will split the string into two parts.

Comment: @sabinadhikari yes this will for Ireland... but so how can I deal with Portuguese address: ESTR DA PORTELA N 9 PORTELA DE CARNAXIDE 2790-124 CARNAXIDE ?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your address with array using PHP function `explode(",",$address)`. It will separate your address after ", " and store in array...

Answer (score 0):

Parsing addresses is challenging because of the many formats you will encounter, even within a single country. There are services that can parse the input and even verify whether the address exists. They usually return the address in components as well as a composed whole. Unfortunately, parsing international addresses is usually only available via a paid service. One such service is provided by smartystreets.com:

- [International API documentation](https://smartystreets.com/docs/international)
- [International output fields](https://smartystreets.com/docs/international#http-response-output)

(Disclosure: I'm a developer at smartystreets.)